# Youtube-dl acting up in Kubuntu 18.04 "can't download"

Tags: ffmpeg, download, youtube, youtube-dl, aria2

first thing I'd like to state that I didn't have any issues using youtube-dl in Windows 10. But not in Kubuntu 18.04, It doesn't work

the command:

`$ sudo youtube-dl 'IllgR6kOieI' --external-downloader aria2c --external-downloader-args '-c -j 3 -x 3 -s 3 -k 1M' -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio' --merge-output-format mp4 -o "%(playlist_title)s/%(playlist_index)s_%(title)s.%(ext)s" -i -w -c`

the output:

`[youtube] IllgR6kOieI: Downloading webpage`

`[youtube] IllgR6kOieI: Downloading video info webpage`

`WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone`

`WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone`

`WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone`

`WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone`

`WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone`

`ERROR: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

PS: I've already installed aria2c and ffmpeg as well

EDIT:

by downloading the latest version of youtube-dl, the error has been fixed.
thanx

Comment: Did you install `youtube-dl` via `apt`? If so, it's likely a much older version. Remove it and download the latest version from [ytdl.org](https://yt-dl.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using pigeonburger's suggestion I removed the youtube-dl installed with apt and reinstalled it using instructions from [this link](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)
but instead of downloading the copy to `/usr/local/bin`, I downloaded it to `/usr/bin`.

many thanx

PS: If you run

> youtube-dl --update

technically this problem should go away even with apt's youtube-dl